# Error editing Read-Only word files after clicking Edit document

Tags: 2010, word, check-out

When I click a link to a Word file in SharePoint Document Library, it asked if I want to open it.

If the file is checked out, I can edit the document.

If the file is **not** checked out, it will open in **Read-Only** mode with the option to Edit Document. *"READ-ONLY We opened this document read-only from the server"*

If I press edit document it will pop up a message about *"We're having trouble connecting to the server. If this keeps happening, contact your help desk."*

I know you probably can't edit a document that is not checked out, but why don't the user get the option to check out the document from word?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document Library that has the problem is created with Visual Studio. Creating a new Document Library in that Site will not cause the problem.

It seems like Microsoft Word is trying to access the library by using URL composed as webUrl + Library.

To avoid this problem, the Document Library has to be created without the “/Lists/” part.

Good Url for document libraries: webUrl/DocumentLibrary1
Bad Url for document libraries: webUrl/Lists/DocumentLibrary1

Found the information [here](http://naimmurati.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/edit-document-instead-of-check-out-when-opening-a-word-document/)